# Encoding of the pop3 server response

Tags: c#, encoding, pop3

I read that pop3 server returns it's responses in ASCII encoding. But i met that some information wasn't encoded and was returned in national codepage (encoding).

for example:
"Subject: Вася Пупкин шлет приветы" (simple text in windows-1251) instead of "Subject: encoded in windows-1251 text"

So, must i use Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) instead of ASCII for processing pop3 stream? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The raw messages that you fetch from the POP3 server will be in whatever encoding they arrived at the POP3 server in - the POP3 server won't re-encode them.

What is meant by the POP3 server's responses being in ASCII is the +OK and -ERR responses.

I've started writing a mail client library called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) that can handle this all for you. It's built on top of my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library that does all of the MIME parsing.